# Fruit Tea- Tastes Sour?

Tags: fruit, tea

I've been trying to get into teas with more fruity flavors (pieces of fruit in the tea or tea based on fruit pieces) and I've noticed that a large majority of them have unpleasantly sour notes. Am I brewing incorrectly or is something else supposed to be added into the tea?

EDIT: It's teas that already have fruit pieces in them, and doesn't appear to be a particular fruit of any sort. I just steep tea leaves in a glass for a few minutes, usually with near-boiling water, then drink.

Comment: Could you tell us what fruits you're adding?

Comment: How are you brewing the tea? Technique matters.

Comment: @MandoMando I *think* the OP is not actually adding fruits, but rather trying teas which already include some bits of dried fruit for flavor.

Comment: I've tried steeping tea with goji berries, those don't result in a sour flavor. Give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to assume that the sour flavor is not how it's supposed to be. But that may simply be how the tea you've bought always tastes. If it's really sour, maybe it's just not a good tea; it could also be that you simply don't prefer this kind of tea. You could try to cover it up with a bit of sugar. But failing that, I think this is just not the tea for you. There are tons and tons of fruit-flavored teas out there, so I'm sure you can find some different ones to try.

Answer (score 4):

Hibiscus is frequently put into herbal fruit teas, as it gives a rich red colour. It is also quite sour! If you dislike that flavour, you'd best avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Often fruits are treated with ascorbic acid (or similar) to prevent browning due to oxidization during the dehydration (particularly, apples).

This can add the sour notes as well if not already native to the fruit.

Answer (score -1):

If the ingredients include rose hips,  it may be those.

Comment: No, rose buds are not sour at all. I love rosebud verbena tea, and it's slightly sweet.

Comment: Are rose buds and rose hips the same thing?